# 10.9.3 update failed to verify on three attempts, now what?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I've tried to install the 10.9.3 update three times. Each time, the app store downloads, the machine reboots, and then up comes a dialog complaining that it could not verify the update. Upon clicking OK, it reboots and spends 7 minutes putting things back the way it found them.

Disk utility finds nothing to complain of, and there's plenty of space.

Machine is running 10.9.2, and it is a mid-2011 mac mini.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the combo updater instead:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1746

Comment: This answer is accepted. Is my assumption that the problem is resolved justified? I would (and others who come here with the same problem) like to know :)